# How to output array on new lines using PowerShell and Microsoft Teams webhook

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Attempting to post using Teams webhook the count of users in array and each user in array on new line

The user count works as expected, but the user name list does not

I have tried

```
`n`n
```

prints first value in array then nothing more

Below print the values and plus \n\n for example all on one line

```
\n\n

\r\r

\r\n

<br><br>
```

```
$URI = " "

$AD = "abc","bcd","cdb","bva","dfdf","4gfd09","sdf435"

$Date = get-date

$AddUsersList = ($AD -join "\r\r")

write-host "Build Teams message"
    $JSONBody = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    "@type" = "MessageCard"
    "@context" = "<http://schema.org/extensions>"
    "themeColor" = '25bc15'
    "title" = "TEST - $Date"
    "text" = "

    $($AD.count) users were added
    
    $($AddUsersList)
    "
    }

    $TeamMessageBody = ConvertTo-Json $JSONBody

    $parameters = @{
    "URI" = $URI
    "Method" = 'POST'
    "Body" = $TeamMessageBody
    "ContentType" = 'application/json'
    }

Invoke-RestMethod @parameters
```

Comment: Teams webhooks are currently broken, you are likely hitting this bug: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/incoming-webhook-messages-not-displaying-in-latest/f42a0466-8a63-4523-a4c2-ee3d8463a0e3

Comment: Have you tried `$AddUsersList = $AD -join [environment]::NewLine` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new line to array using PowerShell, you have to use the pipe operator to pipe the array variable to Out-String.

Let’s consider an example of an Employee array having employee names stored in an array variable as below

> ```
> $EmployeeArrayList = 'Tom Smith','Adam Strauss','Tim Smith','Gary willy'
> $empArray = $EmployeeArrayList  | Out-String
> Write-Host $empArray
> ```

The output of the above script in PowerShell to add new line in Array as below

[image]

Comment: Tried Out-String, but same issue in Teams as other options. Thinking it is the bug Vinny mentioned

Comment: The issue is resolved-https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/incoming-webhook-messages-not-displaying-in-latest/f42a0466-8a63-4523-a4c2-ee3d8463a0e3?page=4
Could you please check it once?